# ASIHTTPRequest code design

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, oop, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to communicate with the server asynchronously. It works great, but I'm doing requests in different controllers and now duplicated methods are in all those controllers. What is the best way to abstract that code (requests) in a single class, so I can easily re-use the code, so I can keep the controllers more simple. I can put it in a singleton (or in the app delegate), but I don't think that's a good approach. Or maybe make my own protocol for it with delegate callback.

Any advice on a good design approach would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I am using subclasses of Ben Copsey's `ASIHTTPRequest` very heavily for a web service client I hope to finish in the next couple weeks. It's a great project and his work has saved me a great deal of time and effort.

I have an `ASINetworkQueue` set up in the application delegate. The queue is sent the `-go` message so that it is ready to receive requests. I add my subclassed requests to this queue. Each request is processed and issues its notifications, and my view controller handles the response data accordingly.

What I have done is subclass `ASIHTTPRequest` and:

1. Set up an `-init` method (or `-initWithParams:` method, depending on the request)
2. Override `-requestFailed:` and `-requestCompleted:` to handle HTTP error messages coming back from the web service
3. My view controllers register to observe `NSNotification` notifications that come from error handling in the `-requestCompleted:` method

As view controllers are pushed on and popped off the navigation stack, I add and remove different registrations. Some view controllers only need to listen for certain subclassed request types.

Listening for `NSNotification` allows me to issue `UIAlertView` dialogs to let the user know something went wrong, or to handle the request response data (feeding results into a Core Data store, for example) when the request yields a successful HTTP error.

Whether the request succeeds or fails, I remember to `-release` the request when I'm done with it.

Comment: Do you have to deal with access token on the server side? In my case I have to send out 3-4 requests, and I am not sure if they will succeed or fail. If they fail, I will have to ask for a new access token, and then rerun the failed requests. Also I one failed, there is no reason to run the others until I get the new token. And when that is available, just rerun the ones in the waiting queue.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a singleton class to handle this.

```
static  TCHttpRequest *_sharedHttpRequest = nil;
+ (id)sharedRequest
{
    @synchronized(self){
        if (_sharedHttpRequest == nil) {
            _sharedHttpRequest = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return  _sharedHttpRequest;
}


- (NSDictionary *)loginWithUserName:(NSString *)user password:(NSString *)pwd
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/login" relativeToURL:_url];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setCachePolicy:ASICacheForSessionDurationCacheStoragePolicy];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:HTTP_REQ_TIMEOUT];
    [request addPostValue:user forKey:@"username"];
    [request addPostValue:pwd forKey:@"password"];
    request.delegate = self.delegate;
    [_common_queue addOperation:request];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see how the class method and the instance method are related? The class method instantiates TCHttpRequest and guarantees only a single instance. The loginWithUserName instance method instantiates a ASIFormDataRequest and adds it to a common queue. I do not see any reuse here?